# pandas get numpy ndarray using series.values

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pandas, series

I want to convert a `series` to `numpy.ndarray`, so that using `ndarray` can lead to great time efficientcy improvement,

```
numpy_martix = df[some_col].values
```

I found that `series.values` itself took a bit of time to do the conversion, so I wondering is there faster way to do it.

Comment: How long is "a bit of time", and how large is your dataframe?

Comment: Have you tried `as_matrix`?

Comment: @Evert the dataframe is about 100k rows, taken about 0.7-0.8 secs

Comment: @IanS using `as_matrix` doesn't gain any improvement

Comment: 100k rows copied (converted) to a numpy array in less than 1 second isn't fast, but not too slow either. If you're doing this continuously in a loop of sorts, perhaps you need to look at another way to structure your program flow.

Comment: Are you sure it's taking that long? There is no conversion to do when accessing `.values`. For a dataframe of 1m rows it's taking 2.36 µs for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(**Edited**)

When you call `arr = df.values`, a reference to `df` data is returned, so it's very fast (no real job done). On the other hand, `arr = df[list_of_cols].values` requires some consolidation inside `df` first.

Try running it this way:

```
arr = df.values[:, numeric_list_of_cols]
```

It may be a bit faster because all the work is done inside numpy array. But the actual speedup may very well depend on the underlying data.

### Tests

I decided to run some tests and here are the results.

First, a data frame containing only numeric values.

```
'''Setup'''
a = np.random.rand(1000, 1000)
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
idx = np.arange(0, 1000, 3)

df.iloc[:3,:5]
Out[35]: 
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.825100  0.556511  0.445429  0.972720  0.726258
1  0.818005  0.298689  0.684203  0.722038  0.848657
2  0.426488  0.270172  0.400533  0.946921  0.745236
```

Let's get every third column:

```
# data frame:
%timeit x = df.iloc[:,idx]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.69 ms per loop
%timeit x = df.iloc[:,idx].copy()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.75 ms per loop

# underlying values:
%timeit x = df.values[:,idx]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.61 ms per loop
%timeit x = df.values[:,idx].copy()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.23 ms per loop

# numpy array for comparison
%timeit x = a[:,idx]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.53 ms per loop
%timeit x = a[:,idx].copy()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.16 ms per loop
```

Accessing with `.values` is only a little bit faster (in fact, on other tests I ran the difference was even smaller, less than 1%). But let's try the same with a contiguous group of columns.

```
%timeit x = df.iloc[:,300:600]
10000 loops, best of 3: 153 µs per loop
%timeit x = df.iloc[:,300:600].copy()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.18 ms per loop

%timeit x = df.values[:,300:600]
The slowest run took 9.67 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 15.7 µs per loop
%timeit x = df.values[:,300:600].copy()
1000 loops, best of 3: 568 µs per loop

%timeit x = a[:,300:600]
The slowest run took 24.73 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 414 ns per loop
%timeit x = a[:,300:600].copy()
1000 loops, best of 3: 497 µs per loop
```

We can suspect that we're getting view sometimes. So let's concentrate on results for `.copy()`. Accessing with `values` is roughly 2 times faster.

We can do even better. Let's change the layout of the data in the underlying array to fortran order. It means that columns of the array are laid contiguously in memory (not rows, which is default).

```
a = np.asfortranarray(a)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.asfortranarray(a))
df.iloc[:3,:5]
df.iloc[:3,:5]
Out[53]: 
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.825100  0.556511  0.445429  0.972720  0.726258
1  0.818005  0.298689  0.684203  0.722038  0.848657
2  0.426488  0.270172  0.400533  0.946921  0.745236
```

I'm pasting only the results for copying:

```
# Every third column:
%timeit x = df.iloc[:,idx].copy()
100 loops, best of 3: 1.85 ms per loop
%timeit x = df.values[:,idx].copy()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.2 ms per loop
%timeit x = a[:,idx].copy()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.13 ms per loop

# Contiguous group of columns
%timeit x = df.iloc[:,300:600].copy()
1000 loops, best of 3: 635 µs per loop
%timeit x = df.values[:,300:600].copy()
1000 loops, best of 3: 655 µs per loop
%timeit x = a[:,300:600].copy()
1000 loops, best of 3: 586 µs per loop
```

But what happens when a data frame contains columns of mixed types?
Let's convert every second columns to strings.

```
for i in range(0, 1000, 2):
    df[i] = df[i].astype(str)

df.iloc[:3,:5]
Out[71]: 
                0         1               2         3               4
0  0.825100137204  0.556511  0.445428873093  0.972720  0.726258247769
1  0.818005069404  0.298689  0.684203047084  0.722038  0.848656512757
2   0.42648763586  0.270172  0.400532581854  0.946921  0.745235906595

%timeit x = df.iloc[:,idx].copy()
100 loops, best of 3: 8.24 ms per loop
%timeit x = df.values[:,idx].copy()
10 loops, best of 3: 51.6 ms per loop

%timeit x = df.iloc[:,300:600].copy()
100 loops, best of 3: 6.91 ms per loop
%timeit x = df.values[:,300:600].copy()
10 loops, best of 3: 48.3 ms per loop
```

Numpy can't deal that well with mixed types in an array. Direct access to data frame wins hands down.

---

**Appendix**
How to get `numeric_list_of_cols` out of `list_of_columns`.

1. Pure python:

   ```
   cols = df.columns.tolist()
   numeric_list_of_cols = [cols.index(i) for i in list_of_columns]
   ```
2. Numpy:

   ```
   numeric_lis_of_cols, = np.in1d(df.columns, list_of_columns).nonzero()
   ```

   Comma after `numeric_lis_of_cols` is necessary to unpack the tuple. A function `in1d` returns a boolean array and `nonzero()` - a tuple of array(s) of nonzero indices.

   **Warning**: it can change the order of elements.

   To keep the order you can iterate over elements of `list_of_columns` (something like `np.nonzero(df.columns == elem)`) to get subsequent indices.

Comment: I tried `arr = df.values[:, numeric_list_of_cols]`, but got an error `IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`.

Comment: @daiyue Do you substitute numeric indices for `numeric_list_of_cols`? If you have a data frame with columns 'A', 'B', 'C' in this order and want to get 'A' and 'C' then you should do `arr = df.values[:,[0, 2]]`

Comment: how to find the indices of the `numeric_list_of_col` collectively, and passed in `values[]`? say I have a list of columns called `list_of_col`, which is a subset of a `df`, a selective of columns.

Comment: @daiyue See the update. I'm not sure if it's the simplest way but it should work.

Comment: thank you for your input, your answer is definitely one way to get ndarray from a column list

Comment: @daiyue Glad I could help. But is it actually faster?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112998/discussion-between-daiyue-and-ptrj).